# In Node+Express, how can I set CORS for individual routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using express-cors npm package, but any way will do:

I tried this for a public route:

```
// @ /routes/index.js
var cors = require('express-cors');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Set cross-origin rules
router.use(cors({
    allowedOrigins: [
        '*'
    ]
}));

// GET home page
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'tol-node-public' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I also tried a private route to allow access from my website:

```
// Set cross-origin rules
router.use(cors({
     allowedOrigins: [
         'https://*.mysite.*'
     ]
}));
```

But upon my Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.mysite.com/',
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (res) {
        console.log( "NODE SERVER STATUS: " + JSON.stringify(res) );
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, errThrown) {
        if (DEBUG) console.log( "**ERR @ CheckNodeStatus: " + JSON.stringify(res) );
    }
});
```

I am getting an err for no CORS, so access denied. How can I fix my CORS? I am still new at Node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not used `npm express-cors` before, but I have used `npm cors` so I can only discuss how to use that.

To set up:

`npm i -S cors`

---

index.js:

```
// @ /routes/index.js
var cors = require('cors');
var app = require('express')();

// Allow all
app.use(cors());

// GET home page
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'tol-node-public' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

Or set up for your particular api, on a particular route (in this case the root route):

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://api.mysite.com/',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};

app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), function(req, res, next){
  res.render('index', { title: 'tol-node-public' });
});
```

---

There are many other options available using this package.

[Documentation for npm cors here.](https://github.com/expressjs/cors)

Comment: I'm using `var router = express.Router();` - can I use router.use() instead of app.use for this specific router? Trying around your code now

Comment: Yeah, should be fine to use with `Router()`.